# Remove duplicate values between arrays in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Let's say that I have the following arrays:

```sql
SELECT ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'] AS origin_array
UNION ALL
SELECT ['A', 'A', 'B'] AS secondary_array
```

And I want to remove all duplicate values between the arrays (as opposed to within the arrays), so that the final result will be:

```
SELECT ['C', 'A', 'A'] AS result_array
```

Any idea how can it be done?

Comment: please explain the logic of deduping! how the desired result is callculated?

Comment: oh, I think I got it - interesting - what the real use case for it - can you share ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DEDUP_ARRAYS(arr1 ANY TYPE, arr2 ANY TYPE) AS ((ARRAY(
  SELECT item FROM (
    SELECT item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item) pos FROM UNNEST(arr1) item UNION ALL
    SELECT item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item) pos FROM UNNEST(arr2) item
  )
  GROUP BY item, pos
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
)));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'] AS origin_array, ['A', 'A', 'B'] AS secondary_array
)
SELECT DEDUP_ARRAYS(origin_array, secondary_array) AS result_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row result_array     
1   A    
    A    
    C
```

which is what would `SELECT ['C', 'A', 'A'] AS result_array` returned

Comment: Perfect! I have several use cases for them, which all have similar purposes. For example, let's say that I need to sew a 2-piece suit (shirt & pants). I have a list of all the required items for the entire suit, and all the required items for the shirt. If I can subtract the "shirt items" from the "suit items" I can tell exactly which items are required for the pants, and as a result use less data.

Answer (score 0):

If you type just `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` it should not take the duplicate values.